# Error when downloading market data from yahoo finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I have tried downloading market data from yahoo finance, but I kept on running into error. Here is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf

#import data of different asset classes
VT = yf.download("VT",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #stocks
BND = yf.download("BND",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #bonds
VNQ = yf.download("VNG",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #real estate
DBC = yf.download("DBC",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #commodities
```

This Error shows up:

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2a474e2089b7> in <module>
      1 #import data of different asset classes
----> 2 VT = yf.download("VT",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #stocks
      3 BND = yf.download("BND",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #bonds
      4 VNQ = yf.download("VNG",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #real estate
      5 DBC = yf.download("DBC",interval="1d", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-01-01") #commodities

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py in download(tickers, start, end, actions, threads, group_by, auto_adjust, back_adjust, progress, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding, **kwargs)
     93                                    rounding=rounding)
     94         while len(shared._DFS) < len(tickers):
---> 95             _time.sleep(0.01)
     96 
     97     # download synchronously

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: It seems that there are various problems with the current version. In my environment, with the latest version (0.62.1), there are no errors.

Comment: May I know whether there are any other ways to download market data that may be better than yahoo finance?

Comment: I'm sure there are others like [yahoo_fin](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/), [yahooquery](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/), [pandas-datareader](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/devel/), but I personally recommend yfinance.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

tickers = ["AAPL","GOOG","AMZN"]
yf.download(tickers,  start = "2021-02-01" , end = "2021-02-04")
```

Answer (score 0):

your queries are fine, it looks like a timing issue between your network and Yahoo finance, you might want to add a delay between requests or retry
look up retry

Vanguard is great according to Warren Buffet... (VT)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).